# ActiveMQ Artemis and Logstash JMX input

Tags: java, logstash, jmx, activemq-artemis

I want to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis from JMX using logstash and ship data to Elastic.

For Artemis 2.13.0,

`management.xml`:

- commented out the `<authorisation>` tag
- added `<connector connector-port="1099">`

`artemis.profile.cmd`:

- added `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` under JAVA_ARGS, since the Jconsole/Logstash was not able to discover the RMI JMX

Set ELK in my local windows 10 machine
`local-jmx.config`

```
input {
  jmx {
    path => "/path/to/config/"  //This has a file jmxquery.config
    polling_frequency => 60
    nb_thread => 5
    type => "jmx"
  }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

`jmxquery.config` :

```
{
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 1099,
  "url": "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi",
  "username" : "guest",
  "password" : "guest",
   "alias" : "Version",
  "queries" : [
  {
    "object_name" :  "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,attribute=Version" ,
    "object_alias" : "version"
  } 
 ]
}
```

I am able to use `localhost:1099` with JConsole

[image: jconsole local]

However, when I start logstash the JMX is able to connect but there is a message saying, "No jmx object."

```
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,030][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Wait until the queue conf is empty
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,030][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Retrieve config {"host"=>"127.0.0.1", "port"=>1099, "url"=>"service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi", "username"=>"guest", "password"=>"guest", "alias"=>"ActiveMQ", "queries"=>[{"object_name"=>"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,attribute=Version", "object_alias"=>"version"}]} from queue conf
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,031][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Check if jmx connection need a user/password
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,031][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Wait 60s (60-0(seconds wait until queue conf empty)) before to launch again a new jmx metrics collection
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,031][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Connect to 127.0.0.1:1099 with user guest
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,044][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Set base_metric_path to alias: Version
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,044][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Treat queries [{"object_name"=>"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,attribute=Version", "object_alias"=>"version"}]
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,044][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] Find all objects name org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,attribute=Version
[2020-07-29T13:57:40,045][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jmx      ] No jmx object found for org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=0.0.0.0,attribute=Version
```

I expected to return the version number here. Is the object name or configuration incorrect for logstash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with the object_name creation.

Used the console to get the queue object name as below
[image: Artemis console configuration]

And include that in the jmxquery.config

```
...
"queries" : [
  {
    "object_name" :  "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"demo\"" ,
    "object_alias" : "version"
  } 
 ]
....
```

Able to see the info shipped to kibana now.

[image: kibana ui]

Complete configuration, incase to limit the number of attributes to be pushed to Elastic, using `attributes` property.

```json
{
  "host" : "127.0.0.1",
  "port" : 1099,
  "url": "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi",
  "username" : "usern-name",
  "password" : "password-so-it-can-access-jmx-of-artemis",
   "alias" : "ActiveMQ",
  "queries" : [

  {
    "object_name" :  "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"broker-*\",component=addresses,address=*,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=*" ,
    "attributes" : ["Address","MessageCount","ConsumerCount","MessagesAcknowledged"],
     "object_alias" : "${address}"
  }    
 ]
}
```